# Unbiased Estimators Poisson

Tags: statistics

Suppose X ∼ Poisson(λ), instead of estimating λ, we
are interesting in estimating P(X = 0)^2 = e^−2λ. Show that δ(X) = (−1)X is an unbiased estimator for e^−2λ
. Is this a good estimator? Why?

I'm having a bit of trouble starting this problem. I know that equation for Bias and all, but how do I use it to calculate this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\Pr(X=k)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.
It follows that
$$E((-1)^X)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
Bring an $e^{-\lambda}$ out. We get
$$E((-1)^X)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.$$
We recognize the sum after the $e^{-\lambda}$ as the usual power series for $e^{-\lambda}$. It follows that the expectation of $(-1)^X$ is $e^{-2\lambda}$, and therefore $(-1)^X$ is an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2\lambda}$.

As to whether it is a good estimator,  using an estimator that often produces $-1$ as an estimate of a clearly positive quantity sounds quite unreasonable!  It is "on average" right, but has such high variance that it is essentially useless.